# How to output arrays in a certain way using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, explode

I'm try to print an array where every other value is reassigned, as examples (from this):

```
17.34502870451717,62.46137370987033
```

To this:

```
62.46137370987033,17.34502870451717
```

That part have I succeeded with, but now I have this structure:

```
[62.46137370987033,[17.34501402936927,]
[62.46123453616544,[17.34525377433593,]
[62.4610178881864,[17.34546663705899,]
```

This is where I get stuck and do not know how to write.

The structure I want looks like this:

```
[62.392628, 17.309413],
[62.393162, 17.309193],
[62.393403, 17.30922]
```

Here is my **explode.php** ([GIST](https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/6100206))

```
<?php
        $dwarf = "17.34502870451717,62.46137370987033,17.34501402936927,62.46123453616544";
        $minion = explode(",",$dwarf); 
        $wing = "[";
        for ($i = 0;$i < count($minion) -1; $i++) {
                echo $wing . $minion[$i+1].",";
                if($i%2==1) { echo "]<br />"; }
        } echo $minion[0] . $wing;
?>
```

Comment: Your "now I have this structure" does not look well, it seems to be missing end brackets.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That's because I have a "The structure I want.." If I didn't misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, as long as there's always even pairs it should be as easy as;

```
<?php
    $dwarf = "17.34502870451717,62.46137370987033,17.34501402936927,62.46123453616544";
    $minion = explode(",",$dwarf);
    $eol = '';
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($minion) -1; $i+=2) {
       echo $eol.'['.$minion[$i+1].','.$minion[$i]."]";
       $eol=',<br/>';
    }
    echo '<br/>';

>>> [62.46137370987033,17.34502870451717],
>>> [62.46123453616544,17.34501402936927]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 $dwarf = "17.34502870451717,62.46137370987033,17.34501402936927,62.46123453616544";
 $minion = explode(",",$dwarf); 
 $wing = "[";
 for ($i = 0;$i < count($minion) -1; $i+=2) 
 {
       echo  $kk =   $wing . $minion[$i+1].",".$minion[$i]."],<br>";              
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small modification to the given answers

```
$dwarf = "17.34502870451717,62.46137370987033,17.34501402936927,62.46123453616544";
$minion = explode(",",$dwarf); 
$str = '';
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($minion) -1; $i+=2) {
        $str.='['.$minion[$i+1].','.$minion[$i].'],<br/>';
    } 
echo rtrim($str,','); // to trim ',' at the end
```